# using my own equals method for a set

Tags: java, overriding, equals

So i am trying to Override equals() so when i make a set of my objects it will function correctly.

Here is the code i'm working with (ignoring type safety for now)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    MyClass myObject1 = (MyClass) o;
    MyClass myObject2 = (MyClass) this;
    if (myObject1.property == myObject2.property)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You can assume there's only one property and it's a primitive type like an int.

However if i add two of the same objects to a set, they both are added.

Comment: I don't think you need `MyClass myObject2 = (MyClass) this;`. You can get rid of this line and use `myObject1.property == this.property` inside the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you violated [Java requirement for overriding `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Without an implementation of `hashCode` that returns identical values for equal objects a hash set will generally treat objects with distinct hash codes as different, unless there is a hash collision.

Once you implement `hashCode` for your class, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes have to override `equals` and `hashCode`

From the Set [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.
>
> The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those
>   inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all
>   constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode
>   methods.

to override these methods you can do this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // ...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31). // two randomly chosen prime numbers
            // if deriving: appendSuper(super.hashCode()).
            append(name).
            append(age).
            toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        Person rhs = (Person) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().
            // if deriving: appendSuper(super.equals(obj)).
            append(name, rhs.name).
            append(age, rhs.age).
            isEquals();
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/1754020

Comment: I had to mark Dasblinkenlight's as correct because he answered first but i thank you for the help as well

Comment: you're welcome @BenArnao no worries! thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine if you implement the hashCode() method like below.

```
public int hashCode(){
    return this.property.hashCode();
  }
```

Please note it is mandatory to override hashcode method of object class when you overide equals method of object class.

During add method call of a given Set, hashCode method is called first - once they(like a telephone directory index) are same, equals method is checked.